# How to reopen file descriptor 0, 1 and 2?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, file-descriptor

Say in the python *REPL* I, separately, called `os.close` with `0`, `1` and `2` which are the [standard input, output and error](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations). How could I reopen/reinitialize them? Such that I would close them in the start of a function, or code block, and reopen before the return.

*PS: Both python specific and generic details would be much appreciated.*

Comment: Is it fair to duplicate them to another file descriptor, and then duplicate them back?

Comment: @Xymostech I actually asked this question to get some inner(maybe too technical) details of the process. Therefore the answer could as well include *duplication* but the reopening part should be present, or maybe a reason why *duplication* is the only solution

Answer (score 4):

You can't close them and then reopen them, but you can duplicate them and restore the previous value once you're done. Something like this;

```
copy_of_stdin  = os.dup(0)  // Duplicate stdin  to a new descriptor
copy_of_stdout = os.dup(1)  // Duplicate stdout to a new descriptor
copy_of_stderr = os.dup(2)  // Duplicate stderr to a new descriptor
os.closerange(0,2)          // Close stdin/out/err

...redirect stdin/out/err at will...

os.dup2(copy_of_stdin,  0)  // Restore stdin
os.dup2(copy_of_stdout, 1)  // Restore stdout
os.dup2(copy_of_stderr, 2)  // Restore stderr
os.close(copy_of_stdin)     // Close the copies
os.close(copy_of_stdout)
os.close(copy_of_stderr)
```